# Simpe C code physically breaks nucleo boards

Tags: stm32

Code below physically breaks nucleo boards. 2 so far.
ST links is unable to connect and boards are not detected.
first dead one was xncleo stm32f411re, another one is nucleo stm32f446re.
I'm a complete beginner and that is pretty much my first code.
and 2 boards dead;) The question is why it may happen? or can one reset the board harder that normal jumper reset

```
int main()
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR = (1<<0);
    GPIOA->MODER = (1<<5);

    while(1)
    {
            GPIOA->ODR |=  (0<<5);
    }
}
```

This is similar to this question ->
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204996/stm32-st-link-cannot-connect-to-mcu-after-successful-programming
, answer to which helped me to restore the board, however answers to my problem in this thread are also very helpfull.

Comment: So?  You have not asked a question we can answer.

Comment: What ever the question is, the answer: blame it on hardware.

Comment: question is, why does it break the hardware? and how to write it properly maybe

Comment: I am not familiar with nucleo boards, but a quick search shows that `RCC->AHB1ENR` is to enable the clock to a specific gpio. If I am not mistaken you shouldn't be trying to set the value manually but using the stm lib which you also are not using. Take a look at: http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/stm32f4-pin-initialize-without-cmsis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some pins used for debugging need to have some settings. if you change those settings the debugger cannot connect anymore. you need to set the debugger to connect under reset when the debug pins are in the initial corrct state. stm32 processors cannot be bricked this simple way.

so not listen to the advices that you need to use crappy STM libraries. just only set the pins you use, not the whole port.

Comment: Seems like whatever I do using Keil MDK, library or not, ends up breaking ST link. I'll try messing about with the flashing options.

Comment: just do not assign to the modern. use `|=` or `&=` instead

Comment: That was it! :) @P__J__ Doesn't break now. Too low rep to vote though.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:Reseting problem solved here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204996/stm32-st-link-cannot-connect-to-mcu-after-successful-programming

### the reason problem occured solved below

Ok, it doesn't physically break the board. Needed hard reset - shorting rst and sb11 pins on nucleo stm32f446re. didn't try on xnucleo yet.

User P__J__ got it right in the comment. I'll cite:

just do not assign to the moder. use |= or &= instead – P__J__

Done.
And the fixed code:

```
int main()
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;

    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_0;

    while(1)
    {
            GPIOA->ODR |=  GPIO_ODR_OD5;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your problem is with the line "RCC->AHB1ENR = (1<<0);". That enables power to GPIOA, but disables power to the other GPIOs (B,C,D,E, and H on the F411), which includes the SWD pins.